# Unable to set node attribute in runtime and reference it in chef template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am getting template error due to `backend.key=<%= node['key']%`> used in source `key.properties.erb` doesn’t have a value while running shellout.

```
Error : Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError -  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I have a ruby block to get the output of the file `cat /tmp/key.txt` and assigning as a node value.

Ruby block :

```
ruby_block "Get_key" do
    block do
        #tricky way to load this Chef::Mixin::ShellOut utilities
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
        command = 'cat /tmp/key.txt'
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.set['key'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :create
end
```

Erb :

```
backend.key=<%= node['key']%>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `shell_out` to read the contents of a file. Try this instead:

```rb
ruby_block "Get_key" do
  only_if { node['key'] == "" }
  block do
    node.set['key'] = File.read('/tmp/key.txt')
  end
end
```

But I think your actual problem is somewhere else. The error message indicates that `node` is `nil` within your template, which is pretty unusual.

So either I am blind and you really have some typo in the posted template line, or you simplified your code example in such a way that it hides your error. I assume your real template looks more like

```rb
backend.key=<%= node['foo']['key']%>
```

and `foo` not being an array. Check that.

Comment: I am doing a pretty similar thing [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/gerrit/blob/fc82b9d82663f040116aed62bdcc3991e858ab98/recipes/peer_keys.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use this pattern. It's slow and puts extra data in your node object which takes up space and RAM and makes you search index sad. What you want is this:

```
template "whatever" do
  # Other stuff ...
  variables my_file: lazy { IO.read('/tmp/key.txt') }
end
```

That will delay the read until converge time.

Comment: Hi, i tried your approach and got the below value in the template :
backend.key=#<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x00000003d93de0@/opt/chef/cache/cookbooks/cookbookname/recipes/recipe.rb:113>

Comment: I have changed the template erb like below : 
backend.key=<%= @key%>

Comment: Are you using Chef 13? If not that has to be `variables lazy { {key: IO.read(...) } }`.